# eventHandler trigger multiple times when using .on() only

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, event-listener, eventhandler

```
function changeStatus() { 
$('#dataTable tbody').on('change', '.orderStatus', function () {..code} 
}

function showOrdersInModal() { 
    $('#dataTable tbody').on('click', '.fa-eye-btn', function (e) {...code} 
    }
        
function addUrl() { 
$('#dataTable tbody').on('click', '.addUrl', function () {..code} 
}
    
function showOrders() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'method',
    url: 'url',
    data: { data },
    success: function (response) {
      $('#dataTable').DataTable().clear().destroy();

      let data = JSON.parse('[' + response.replace(/}{/g, '},{') + ']');
      
      $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        autoWidth: false,
        pageLength: 25,
        lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100, 500, -1], [25, 50, 100, 500, 'All']],
        data: data,
        columns: [
            { data: 'receipt' },
            { data: 'first_last_name' },
            { data: 'contact_no' },
            { data: 'address' },
            { data: 'email' },
            { data: 'url' },
            { data: 'status' },
        ],
      });

          showOrdersInModal();
          changeStatus();
          addUrl();
    },
  });
}

showOrders();
```

When I use .off() before .on(), the only last function will execute which is `addUrl();` but when I remove the .off() it will trigger the event depending on how many times I click any of each button or element.

Is there a way that I can make the eventHandler trigger once even if I clicked any of the buttons multiple times?

or is there a way to execute all three functions not just the `addUrl();` function at the end?

Comment: `.one( "click", function() {` ??

Comment: I tried this but it does not work, every time I click a button, it keeps adding up so when I click the next button it will trigger multiple times depending on how many times I clicked the previous button.

Comment: Looks like you're adding event listeners every time your ajax call succeeds.

Comment: `.off().on(........` ?

Comment: I use .off().on(...) but only one function will execute which is the addUrl();

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and I found the answer to this. I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and when using the dataTables I cannot access the DOM after the next page so I use [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) which like this:

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
    drawCallback: function () {
      showOrdersInModal();
      changeStatus();
      addUrl();
    },
    retrieve: true,
    deferRender: true,
    data: data,
    columns: [
      { data: 'data' },
    ],
  });
```

then I just use this.

```
$('.className').off().on('click', function () {..code}
```